# Group homomorphism intuition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups. Suppose I'm able to define a non trivial group homomorphism from
$G$ to $H$ what does it actually tell? Is it like $G$ is similar to $H$ in some sense?

Also further I may or may not be able to define a non trivial group homomorphism from $H$ to $G$. Suppose I'm unable to define then from my first conclusion and this can I say $H$ is not similar to $G$ in some sense?

Is my idea correct?

Comment: It tells you that $G/ker\varphi\cong im\varphi\le H$, and that if $ker\varphi$ is trivial then $H$ contains a "copy" of $G$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\phi\colon G\rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism.
Then it depends on the other properties of $\phi$ how "similar" the groups $G$ and $H$ are. Of course, the idea is that $\phi$ is injective and surjective, so that $G$ and $H$ can be viewed as the same group. We say that $G$ and $H$ are *isomorphic* then. If $\phi$ is injective, we can identify $G$ as a subgroup of $H$. If $\phi $ is surjective, then $H$ is a homomorphic image of $G$ and inherits several properties of $G$, like solvability, for example. In general, we can only say that
$$
G/\ker(\phi)\cong \phi(G)\le H.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by “similar” here, but I assuming that, for you, if $G$ is similar to $H$, then $H$ is similar to $G$, then the answer is negative. In fact, there is a non-trivial group homomorphism from $\Bbb Z$ into $\Bbb Z_2$, but there is no non-trivial group homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_2$ into $\Bbb Z$.